# Android kotlin_ Camera intent crashes

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

Maybe this question is a redundancy but the suggested solutions here didn't solve mine.

I am  new in android development, and I'm trying to use camera intent to record a video in my App. I used codes in Android developers guide
https://developer.android.com/training/camera/videobasics

first, I faced (onActivityResult overrides nothing), here I found that I should check Intent if it null-able, this solved the compelling issue but caused the app to be crashed.
and yes I have put the user feature in the manifest file.

Any solutions?

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE = 1

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        btn_record.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "start recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE).also { takeVideoIntent ->
                takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {
                    startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE)
                }
            }   
        }
    }
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val videoUri: Uri = intent!!.data
            videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the crash log?

Comment: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE cmp=com.android.camera2/com.android.camera.VideoCamera } 

surprisingly, the solution was to remove the permission from the manifest file!

Comment: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: exception occur when your app has no permission to access camera or gallery so to provide the permission to app for camera and gallery apply **runtime permission** .before  android os 6.0 there is no need of runtime permisssion but if you are using android version above  5.0 then you need runtime permission.

Comment: `!!` operator is used to explicitly tell the compiler that the property is not null and if it’s null, it will throw exception, so you should put safety check with `?`

Answer (score 1):

Your project needs runtime permission to access camera.
As it falls under dangerous permission set. 
Here is an article for Acquiring Runtime permission for Camera and mic. You can use for your project.
https://pranaybhalerao.wordpress.com/2018/02/11/run-time-permission-in-androidkotlin/
Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set android:exported="true" in your AndroidManifest.xml file where you declare this Activity.

```
<activity
    android:name="MainActivity"
    android:label="Main_Activity" 
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" >
        </action>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```